# I would like to add these for statements together so that i don't have to re-use them everytime i want to delay my text

Tags: python

I would like to add these for statements together so that i don't have to re-use them everytime i want to delay my text

```
import time
import random
import sys
def NewGame():
    text = "Welcome to this game of luck and strategy!\n"
    for i in text:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1);
    # Remove when done time.sleep(2);
    text2 ="In a moment you will recieve a random\nGender, Class, Spawnpoint\n\n"
    for i in text2:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1);
    #time.sleep(2);
    gender = ["Male", "Female"]
    role = ["Warrior", "Mage", "Archer", "Thief", "Robot"]
    text3 = (random.choice(gender))
    for i in text3:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1);
NewGame()
```

Comment: So create a function with the loop and make `text` an argument to that function.

Comment: Write a function for that block and pass `textn` as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a function to combine the re-executing of statements:

```
import time
import random
import sys

def typewriter(text):
    for i in text:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1);

def NewGame():
    typewriter("Welcome to this game of luck and strategy!\n")
    # Remove when done time.sleep(2);
    typewriter("In a moment you will recieve a random\nGender, Class, Spawnpoint\n\n")
    for i in text2:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1);
    #time.sleep(2);
    gender = ["Male", "Female"]
    role = ["Warrior", "Mage", "Archer", "Thief", "Robot"]
    text3 = (random.choice(gender))
    typewriter(text3)
NewGame()
```

Comment: Thanks! now i can continue with practicing python ^^ btw it only worked when i removed the middle for statement with text2

Comment: You're welcome!  I hope it works out for you.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.